# How to convert date to timestamp using Python?

Tags: python, datetime-conversion

I need to convert this result to timestamp:

```
>>> print (datetime.date(2010, 1, 12) + datetime.timedelta(days = 3))
2010-01-15
```

I need to compare the value with this timestamp:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
2011-10-24 10:43:43.371294
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I need to convert this result to timestamp

```
import time


mydate = datetime.date(2010, 1, 12) + datetime.timedelta(days = 3)
time.mktime(mydate.timetuple())
```

> I need to compare the value with this timestamp:

```
a = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 12) + datetime.timedelta(days = 3)
b = datetime.datetime.now()

a < b 
a > b 
a == b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
oneDate = datetime.date(2010, 1, 12) + datetime.timedelta(days = 3)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

The first is `date`, the second is `datetime`. So if you just want to compare the dates (day, month, year), convert the second to `date`:

```
oneDate < now.date()
```

returns `True`

Comment: Hi, tahnks for the reply. I got the error when try to compare: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date

Comment: You really need to call date() on now, otherwise you'll get that error.

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.datetime.now()` will return an instance of datetime.datetime which has a [date()](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date%20date%28%29) method returning an instance of datetime.date. You can then compare that to the result of `datetime.date(2010, 1, 12) + datetime.timedelta(days = 3)`